# Looking for relevant hobby projects for getting started with C#

Tags: c#

I am an experienced software developer in other less common technologies, and now need to ramp up C# skills with VS2010. As an experienced developer, I understand the syntax and language of C# quite quickly.

However, developing windows and web applications with C# is somewhat foreign to me. Can someone please recommend/refer me to **relevant hobby projects that take around a couple of weeks** each that help familiarise developers with the most common API's and approaches to building web and/or windows applications. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get the answer your want here- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Ask around friends and family and I'm sure they'll be at least 1 who wants a "simple little webpage", which will involve "just a button" that will involve some complicated programming :)

Comment: @jump. Doin my cousin's web page is not something that is specficially guided. Not suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeplex is a great resource where you can find projects that want help and join them. See a list of [openings](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search/openings).

Answer (score 1):

I have a project which could use some help refactoring, documenting. It's on SourceForge. Have you tried looking there for Help Wanted listings?